# Quartz Scheduler starting previous job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz clustered, inside a web app. After scheduling some jobs, some of those jobs did not start because quartz could not acquire connections to the DB.

After resolving the DB issue, without clearing the quartz tables i restarted the web app and the jobs did not start. We used the system for various days without scheduling jobs an all seemed ok.

Today we have just scheduled a job which started correctly, the problem is that this seems to have triggered all the other jobs that did not start because of the DB issue.

**NOTE:** we have configured

property `name="autoStartup" value="false"`

property `name="misfireInstructionName" value="MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING"`

**NOTE2:** i don't know if this changes anything but the above jobs are in the same group

Has anybody encountered this behavior?

Comment: What's your Quartz version? Your database + version? ...